# Ubuntu 13.10 Cannot download files with firefox after 7 march 2014 update

Tags: firefox

After today update I cant seem to download any files using firefox.

I can still download and directly with the "Open With" even the extension DownThemAll and Flashgot is working. Other browser also works fine (chromium).

All I get is the download dialogue, click OK and nothing, no error, no download started, nothing....

Anyone can help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Do you have the [Unityfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unityfox/) addon installed? It's the add on which shows the download progress in the unity launcher

Comment: After searching elsewhere it seems the trouble was from firefox itself not from ubuntu.

Using this guide resolve my problem:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/cant-download-or-save-files#w_clear-the-download-history

posting this for future reference if anyone have the same problem

Comment: If you solved your question, please post an answer explaining how it was solved by quoting the steps you did from that link. And posting that link in your answer for reference (Answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)).

Comment: can't yet, 1 point have to wait a couple of more hours....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching elsewhere it seems the trouble was from firefox itself not from ubuntu.

Using this guide resolve my problem:

[What to do if you can't download or save files](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/cant-download-or-save-files#w_clear-the-download-history)

Doing the "Change file type settings" seems to do the trick for me

posting this for future reference if anyone have the same problem